# Laravel how to pass value to Rulee::exist()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have the following code:

```
$postalcode=$data['postal_code'];   
 return Validator::make($data, [
                'name' => ['required','string','max:255'],
                'email' => ['required','string','email','max:255','unique:users'],
                'password' => ['required','string','min:8','confirmed'],
                'postal_code' =>['required','string','max:255',Rule::exists('zipcodes')->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->whereRaw('REPLACE(POSTAL_CODE,\' \',\'\')= ?',[str_replace(' ','',$postalcode)]);
                })],
            ]);
```

but it gives me the following error:

> "Undefined variable: postalcode"

so what I want is to pass variable $postalcode to the rule but I do not know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Rule::exists('zipcodes')->where(function ($query) use($postalcode){
                    $query->whereRaw('REPLACE(POSTAL_CODE,\' \',\'\')= ?',[str_replace(' ','',$postalcode)]);
                });
```

You forgot to write `use($postalcode)`;

Answer (score 0):

```
Try with this, pass paramiter using laravel eager loading (function ($query) use ($postalcode)).Now Don't give Undefined variable: postalcode.

$postalcode=$data['postal_code'];   
 return Validator::make($data, [
                    'name' => ['required','string','max:255'],
                    'email' => ['required','string','email','max:255','unique:users'],
                    'password' => ['required','string','min:8','confirmed'],
                    'postal_code' =>['required','string','max:255',Rule::exists('zipcodes')->where(function ($query) use ($postalcode){
                        $query->whereRaw('REPLACE(POSTAL_CODE)= ?',[str_replace(' ','',$postalcode)]);
                    })],
                ]);
```